# SQL (postgres) to ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having a hard time converting this SQL query to ActiveRecord.  Here's my SQL.

```
SELECT distinct stc_term_gpa,
    user_id,
    lesley_id,
    first,
    last,
FROM lesley_grades
ORDER BY user_id
```

and this returns 437 rows - which is want I want.  I have no problems runnings this in SQL

But when I try to run this in Rails in the Console:

```
LesleyGrade.select(:stc_term_gpa, :user_id, :lesley_id, :first, :last).distinct.order(:user_id)
```

I verified the count in rails

```
LesleyGrade.select(:stc_term_gpa, :user_id, :lesley_id, :first, :last).distinct.order(:user_id).count(:all)
```

I return 1440 rows - which is not what I want...that's all the data rows in my DB.

What's going on?

**UPDATE**

This is strange:

When I run the active record query in Rails Console and get the count 1440

```
LesleyGrade.select(:stc_term_gpa, :user_id, :lesley_id, :first, :last).distinct.order(:user_id).count(:all)
```

I check the SQL in the console (the one that ActiveRecord produces) and this is what it produces:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    "lesley_grades"."stc_term_gpa", 
    "lesley_grades"."user_id", 
    "lesley_grades"."lesley_id", 
    "lesley_grades"."first", 
    "lesley_grades"."last" 
FROM "lesley_grades"   
ORDER BY "lesley_grades"."user_id" ASC
```

When I run the above SQL in a SQL client I get the 437 rows.  Again a discrepancy.

**HOWEVER** when I'm playing with the SQL that rails produces, and take the above statement and add in lesley_grades.id in the projection on my own accord and running raw SQL in a client like this, I get 1440 row (shouldn't it still be getting 437 even if I place the ID there?)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    "lesley_grades"."stc_term_gpa", 
   **"lesley_grades"."id"**, 
    "lesley_grades"."user_id", 
    "lesley_grades"."lesley_id", 
    "lesley_grades"."first", 
    "lesley_grades"."last"
FROM "lesley_grades"
ORDER BY "lesley_grades"."user_id" ASC
```

So I guess the question is does ActiveRecord some how use the ID for something in the a query sneakily, which is why I'm receiving 1440? How do I get my distinct 437 rows?

Comment: Argh, thanks...there are some inconsistencies.  Let me re-edit this.

Comment: But doesn't your AR call produce the same SQL? You can toss a `to_sql` call on the end to see what it does.

Comment: yea it's so weird....here's what I found out...look at the edits above and since the text will become more clear...

Comment: What version of Rails is this? I'm not seeing the `id` show up in Rails4 unless I ask for it.

Comment: Correct, what that is suppose to say is, when I add the ID in the projection in the raw SQL query, only then does it return 1440 rows.  (Rails 4.2 btw)

Comment: The DISTINCT becomes irrelevant once you throw the `id` in since that's the primary key. For the rest, are you sure you're connecting to the same database and running exactly the same SQL?

Comment: Positive...I'm combing through each word and period and quote.

Comment: Would you like to take this to chat?  I'm just as baffled as you are.

Comment: I think I might have found the answer.  `.count(:all)` isn't returning what I was expecting.  It's literally returning ALLLL the rows.  I opted for `.collect.count`  I'm still baffled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77276/discussion-between-gary1410-and-mu-is-too-short).

Answer (score 0):

You can still use find_by_sql metod

```
query = "SELECT distinct stc_term_gpa, user_id,lesley_id,first,last
         FROM lesley_grades
         ORDER BY user_id"
expectedResult = LesleyGrade.find_by_sql(query)
```